# Can't find the error in this form

Tags: php, html, syntax

This is basic stuff but I can't get this following form to process reliably. The name of the page is inplain.php. It works occasionally. The page simply lists all the values in the 'platform' table and allows the user to add a record and refresh.

```
<?
session_start();
   if (!isset($_SESSION['id_customer'])) { die ("Access Denied"); }
   include "../inc/db.php";


   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

     $platform = $_POST['platform'];

     $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

     $query = "INSERT INTO Platform (id_platform, platform, date_created, date_modified) VALUES ('', $platform, '$created', '$created')";
     mysql_query($query);
     mysql_close();

     header("Location: inplain.php");
     }


      echo $passage;

?>




<table cellpadding="15">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="50%">
            <?                   
            $sell_result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id_platform) FROM Platform");
            $sell_count=mysql_fetch_array($sell_result);
            ?>
            The following <?=$sell_count['COUNT(id_platform)']?> categories exist in Platform. | <a href="inlist.php">Add Game...</a>
            <div style="height: 250px; overflow: auto;">
                <ul>
                <?
                    $result = mysql_query("
                                        SELECT * FROM Platform");
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>
                    <li>

                                            <a href="inwant.php?addswaps=1&cat=Sell&col=sell&hid=<?=$row['id_platform']?>"><?=$row['id_platform']?></a> - <?=$row['platform']?>
                        <img src="../images/dot.png" width="1" height="20" border="0" /> 
                        <a href="inplain.php?remove=1&cat=Platform&col=platform&pid=<?=$row['id_platform']?>"><img src="../images/delete.jpg" width="15" height="15" border="0" alt="Delete" /></a>
                    </li>
                <? } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>           
    </tr>   
<tr>
<td>
    <form name="inplain.php" method="post">
        Add a new platform: 
        <br />
            <input type="text" name="platform" size="30" /><BR>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />

    </form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for the suggestions, this finally worked in the end, I added this in place of the "if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {"

```
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

if ($_POST['Submit'] == 'Add' & $password == 'xyd')  {

$platform = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['platform']);

$created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$query = "INSERT INTO Platform (id_platform, platform, date_created, date_modified) VALUES ('', '$platform', '$created', '$created')";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
  header("Location: inplain.php");
    die();
}
```

Comment: "it's broken. fix it. you don't need ot know anything about how it's broken". Perhaps if you fixed your SQL injection holes, it wouldn't be quite as broken.

Comment: "It works occasionally.". And the rest of the time it does....?

Comment: I took out all the sql injection stuff to figure out why it's not working Marc.

Comment: `echo $passage;` won't output anything if it's not defined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `exit` after writing your `Location` header. writing additional output might break the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You should output the results of your mysql query and use the mysql_error function to determine if something is failing sometimes in your query. I notice you are not putting quotes around the $platform variable in your insert so that could be an issue.

Also, note that your script is vulnerable to sql injection. You need to escape your $platform string using mysql_real_escape_string before inserting it.

Lastly, in your Submit logic, just after issuing the header for the redirect back to the script you should put a die() command to stop the script from any further processing while the browser is redirecting. Not required, but good practice.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the suggestions. I do have the obligatory sql injection protection in there, I just stripped it down to raw data so I could try to figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth checking the error logs of MySQL and PHP.

Is it possible that the failures are related to where the script was called from, since I notice that your database details are in an include with a relative path. If this script is also 'included' rather than being run directly, perhaps that relative path is not always correct?